# InstallAnywhere - Uninstallation Java Error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No product for ID=

Tags: uninstallation, installanywhere

I am trying to uninstall an application which is using InstallAnywhere. When I run the code to uninstall i get the following error

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No product for ID=<edited>
        at ZeroGfc.<init>(DashoA10*..)
        at ZeroGe9.b(DashoA10*..)
        at ZeroGfb.<init>(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.Installer.s(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.Installer.setMetadata(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.InstallerMetaData.setInstaller(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.j(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.e(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.a(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.a(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(DashoA10*..)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(DashoA10*..)
This Application has Unexpectedly Quit: Invocation of this Java Application has caused an InvocationTargetException. This application will now exit. (LAX)
```

A thorough search in the internet tells that this error is quite common, but i haven't sen any definite solution for this. 
Will be absolutely helpful if some one can throw light on this...

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows try to clean `c:\Program Files (x86)\Zero G Registry\` folder

Comment: By clean do you mean delete everything there? Because my `Zero G Registry` folder is empty.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to reinstall the product into the same directory as before, clobbering the files that are already there. After it completes successfully, the uninstaller should be usable.

I've seen this when trying to uninstall an incomplete installation. In my particular case, the installer was calling out to a process that sometimes rebooted the machine mid-install, resulting in an empty Zero G Registry. This causes the uninstaller to fail since it cannot find the product GUID.

Comment: In my case the installer fails too, so I seem to be screwed.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue by running in compatibility mode.

Right click on installer -> Properties -> Compatibility -> Compatibility Mode -> Check "Run this program in compatibility mode for (which version)

For me is Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when you just have a stripped-down JRE installed.  Installing the full JDK and pointing InstallAnywhere to it should fix the problem.  You can do this by adding this to the command you're running:

foo.exe LAX_VM "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe"

Obviously replace foo.exe with the command you're running and give the correct path to your JDK Java executable.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this problem today. I have Windows 10 and the program only supports Windows 7. Set Compatibility Mode to Windows 7 doesnt work for me. But this way does:
Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment variables -> Add new user variable:

- Name: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
- Value: "-Dos.name=Windows 7"

Hope this helps someone who needs to install age-old software